# Online Test Script

Tags: php, html, scripting

I am wondering if there is an open source or freeware scripts that is an online test type software. For example of the script I am after I want to be able to ask a question and than a user answer it. And a timer if possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several here:
http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=php+question+answers

and a few more here (but some are commercial - pay-for):
http://www.hotscripts.com/search/php/question+answer+time

Answer (score 1):

[PHPAskIt](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/FAQ-and-Knowledgebase/PHPAskIt-44379.html), [Question2Answer - looks like SO a bit ;)](http://www.question2answer.org/) only for example, there are some more out there.

Here is a [list](http://www.enfew.com/9-free-stackoverflow-clones-and-qa-scripts/) with 9 tools, but not all are written in php.